# Parsing RSS with php to get a json feed

Tags: php, jquery, json, xml, rss

I need to convert a RSS feed from another domain and turn it into json. In order to circumvent cross-domain warnings, I'm parsing the RSS feed server side using this [PHP proxy](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/master/ba-simple-proxy.php) script.

- but somehow the response is in one long string.

I would like to use ajax like this:

```
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.net/simple-proxy.php?url=http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml?edition=int&callback=feed";
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

- but somehow the response is in one long string. How do I get the response turned into a json array with nodes, and so on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution using [SQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Get the string and then convert it into JSON:
I see you are using jquery so...

```
$.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Comment: Doing this throws an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Could it be related to quotes or something?

Comment: Check the data type of the     data variable, if it is already JSON it will give you such an error. Otherwise, make sure you have set the correct headers. 
If the header is already application/JSON you dont need to parse.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I do that in the PHP Proxy above?

Comment: To set the PHP headers, use: 
     header('application/json');

But i reccomend checking the type in JS:

     console.log(typeof data);